# Accessing AngularJs Directive Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am having a few problems accessing my controller on a directive that I am trying to unit test with jasmine and karma testrunner. The directive looks like this:

directive

```
angular.module('Common.accountSearch',['ngRoute'])

    .directive('accountSearch', [function() {
        return {
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $routeParams, $http) {

                this.setAccount = function () {
                    var response = { AccountId : $scope.ctrl.searchedAccount.AccountId }
                    $scope.callback(response)
                }


                this.getAccounts = function(searchText){
                    return $http.get('/api/CRMAccounts', {
                        params: {
                            retrievalLimit: 10,
                            search: searchText
                        }
                    }).then(function(response){
                        return response.data;
                    });

                }

            },
            scope : {
                config : '=',
                values : '=',
                callback : '='
            },
            templateUrl : '/common/components/account-search/account-search.html',
            restrict : 'EAC'
        }
    }]);
```

This here is the test case file so far I believe all is in order and correct (I hope):

test case file:

```
    describe("Account search directive logic tests", function (){
  var element,$scope,scope,controller,template

  beforeEach(module("Common.accountSearch"))


  beforeEach(inject( function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_,_$controller_,$templateCache) {
    template = $templateCache.get("components/account-search/account-search.html")
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $controller = _$controller_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = $compile(template)(scope)
    ctrl = element.controller
    scope.$digest();
  //  httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));




  it(" sets the account and calls back.", inject(function () {

    console.log(ctrl)
    expect(ctrl).toBeDefined()
   }));
  //httpBackend.flush()
});
```

I have managed to print the controller of the directive ( I think) to the console which returns the following ambiguous message:

```
LOG: function (arg1, arg2) { ... }
```

I cannot access any of the functions  or properties on the directive as they are all returning "undefined", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can access it like this `scope.ctrl`

Comment: I find it easier of the controller is it own file, that you could perhaps test easier without the context of a directive

Comment: I have tried scope.ctrl , it was one of the fist things I did and it did not work

Comment: I don't get it, what are you trying to test ? That your directive search properly ? Then you should not try to get the controller to call it, since it is not how your directive is used. You should try to parse a template using the directive and mock a user action which will trigger the directive to search as it was a user action.

Comment: Just for the sake of the question, Your var definition is named as 'controller' but then you try accessing it as 'ctrl'? That would not create a local variable? It may be just a typo when you made the question though.

Answer (score 6):

Controllers for directives are actually fully injectable - instead of providing a constructor, you can just refer to the controller by name. See the directive definition object docs for Angular here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object

In your case where you want to unit test the controller you'd just do it like this:

**common.accountSearch.js**

```
angular.module('Common.accountSearch', [])
  .directive('accountSearch', [function () {
      return {
          controller: 'accountSearchCtrl',
          scope: {
              config    : '=',
              values    : '=',
              callback  : '='
          },
          templateUrl : '/common/components/account-search/account-search.html',
          restrict: 'EAC'
      }
  }])
  .controller('accountSearchCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.setAccount = function () {
          var response = {
              AccountId: $scope.ctrl.searchedAccount.AccountId
          };
          $scope.callback(response);
      }

      $scope.getAccounts = function (searchText) {
          // Code goes here...
      }
  }]);
```

**common.accountSearch-spec.js**

```
describe("Account search directive logic tests", function () {    
    var controller, scope;

    beforeEach(module("Common.accountSearch"));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {        
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = _$controller_('accountSearchCtrl', { '$scope': scope });        
    }));

    it(" sets the account and calls back.", function () {
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

This way you can just inject your controller directly into your jasmine tests like any of your other controllers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ive tried this and it doesnt work. Can you add an example?

Comment: Hmm, guess I made a mistake somewhere. I'll throw together a working fiddle when I've got fifteen minutes, and update my answer.

Comment: Alright, I've tested and updated my answer. To simplify, I removed a few of the dependencies from the controller, but you should just be able to add them back in one-by-one as you develop your mocks and specs. The above will definitely inject the accountSearchCtrl both into the spec, and into the directive, which will fullfil your requirement of unit testing your directive's controller.

Answer (score 6):

So close!

`element.controller` is a function and needs to be passed the name of the directive which you're attempting to get the controller for. In this case it would be

```
ctrl = element.controller("accountSearch");
```

Comment: Where is the doc for this function? Can you post a link?

Answer (score 0):

`element.controller` is an additional method to AngularJS jqLite, so when you log it you see jqLite method `.toString()`. You should call it and get a directive controller. [Element controller manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods)